# LostFocus() event not triggered after application installation

Tags: installation, vb6

I have simple code in the `LostFocus` event of a textbox control
that changes the text to upper case:

```
Private Sub txtIntegration_LostFocus()
    If Trim(txtIntegration.Text) <> "" Then
        txtIntegration.Text = UCase(Trim(txtIntegration.Text))
    End If
End Sub
```

When the application is installed, the code to uppercase the text does not work in.

I'm creating the installer with the "Package and Deployment Wizard" of Visual Basic 6.

Comment: Before deploying it, when you run the EXE on your machine, does this code work as you expect it to?

Comment: Unrelated note: make it a habit to use the String instead of the Variant versions of string handling functions whenever possible, e.g. `Ucase$()` instead of `UCase()`. See [this explanation](https://www.aivosto.com/articles/stringopt.html).

Comment: Do you really need the check for "" first?

Comment: How have you concluded that the installation process has anything to do with this code? Maybe you are simply installing the wrong file or an old version of the program.

Comment: And, does this code work in the IDE?

Comment: @DaveInCaz yes it run in the IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, when you add or remove the program, the removal program does not uninstall the .EXE completely
Simply delete the Directory and solve it!

Answer (score 0):

As a troubleshooting step and potential solution for what you are trying to achieve, you can force the text to uppercase as it is being typed:

```
Private Sub txtIntegration_Change()
    Dim iPosition As Integer
    With txtIntegration
        iPosition = .SelStart ' Save cursor position
        .Text = UCase$(.Text)
        .SelStart = iPosition  ' Restore cursor position
    End With
End Sub
```

You can at least try this approach and see if it works once installed. There should be no reason the installation process breaks any of your code.

Comment: that's not the principal problem, the problem is the instalation don't Take the changes!, thanks anyway!! :D :)

Comment: When you say that the installation doesn't take the changes, do you mean you have made changes to your code and after creating an installer, those changes don't appear in the installed version? Is this a DLL or EXE project? Have you rebuilt the DLL/EXE after you made your changes (File > Make project_name.exe) ?

Comment: Yes! and yes is a EXE project, yes I rebuilt the Exe

Comment: Just to see, I would try adding the code I gave you, build a new EXE and Installer. If that code works, then I suspect the issue is not with installation but with the Focus not going to any other control on your form.